# Converting an Interop Word.Document object to a Stream

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, syncfusion

```
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;
        object fileName = "C:\\Users\\10603726\\Desktop\\test.doc";
        ApplicationClass applicationWord = new ApplicationClass();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document newsDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        try
        {

            newsDoc = applicationWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref  missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            newsDoc.Activate();

            //I want to convert this document to a System.IO.Stream
        }
```

I am opening a document(newsDoc) from disk.  I want to convert this **newsDoc** Document to a System.IO.Stream How can I do this?

Comment: Can you just not open it with stream reader and forego the office interop? I guess the better question is why/what do you need to do?

Comment: I am actually debugging somebody else's code. Don't want to skip this step.

Comment: Yes but what are you needing to do with the stream? Because it looks like all the interop does is open the word document. If that's the case just open it with a files stream.

Comment: File.Open method returns a System.IO.FileStream, which inherits from System.IO.Stream: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx. Why you want to open a structured document as stream?